# dos tablas en una vista Asp.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Buen dia compañeros una pregunta de novato en ASP.NET MVC para poner datos de dos tablas diferentes ¿necesito crear una tercer clase para que se puedan ver los datos en una sola vista?. Si me pudieran dar un ejemplo en codigo o tutorial se los agredeceria mucho.

Comment: El funcionamiento de este sitio no es como tal acerca de peticiones, se basa en preguntas y respuestas puntuales de programación. Si mostraras las investigaciones que has realizado, y algunas pruebas o segmentos de código de lo que tienes, estoy seguro que tu pregunta será mejor recibida y obtendrá mayor atención.

Comment: brother, ya que inicias en el desarrollo con ASP.net MVC, revisa este workshop de 4 horas 4 minutos 4 segundos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el patrón de arquitectura MVC, la parte de 'Modelo' se refiere a la representación de la información/datos que compone el sistema, y usualmente en asp .net mvc es una correspondencia de clases con las tablas de la base de datos. Es por eso que se ha creado el concepto de clases ViewModel, que son clases especificas para mostrar información/datos que solo pertenecen a la vista.

Así que sí, tu aproximación a la solución del problema es correcta. Esa tercer clase que estas pensando crear sería tu ViewModel. Y es tan sencillo como:

ViewModel

```
namespace WebApplication3.ViewModels
{
    public class ViewModel1
    {
        public Table1 table1 { get; set; }
        public Table2 table2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewModel1 viewModel1 = new ViewModel1();
    return View(viewModel1);
}
```

Vista

```
@model WebApplication3.ViewModels.ViewModel1
```